# Menu based shell script to delete files

Tags: shell

My requirement is to delete file based on it displayed. Following is code snippet where I listed files but when I select option it displays file and when I capture file name its not happening only getting key not VALUE($REPLY only displays key but not value). Can someone help me out.

```
#!/bin/bash
    select list in $(ls *.tmp)
    do
            echo  $list
            echo Do you want to delete files ?
            read userInput
            echo "UserInput is :: "  $userInput
            echo "Reply is :: " $REPLY
            if [ $userInput == $REPLY ] ; then
            #       rm $REPLY
                    echo 'Yes'
                    break
    done
```

----OUTPUT-----

```
1) +~JF1905393034413613060.tmp
 2) +~JF2032005334435574091.tmp
 3) +~JF3116454937363220082.tmp
 4) +~JF3334986634800781310.tmp
 5) +~JF3651229840772890748.tmp
 6) +~JF3882306323060007639.tmp
 7) +~JF573641658479505435.tmp
 8) +~JF6137053351660236007.tmp
 9) +~JF6277682393160684532.tmp
10) +~JF6385610668752278364.tmp
11) +~JF6824954027739238354.tmp
12) +~JF7876557427734797684.tmp
#? 4
+~JF3334986634800781310.tmp
Do you want to delete files ?
y
UserInput is ::  y
Reply is ::  4
No
```

Comment: Output for better understanding....

 1) +~JF1905393034413613060.tmp
 2) +~JF2032005334435574091.tmp
 3) +~JF3116454937363220082.tmp
 4) +~JF3334986634800781310.tmp
 5) +~JF3651229840772890748.tmp
 6) +~JF3882306323060007639.tmp
 7) +~JF573641658479505435.tmp
 8) +~JF6137053351660236007.tmp
 9) +~JF6277682393160684532.tmp
10) +~JF6385610668752278364.tmp
11) +~JF6824954027739238354.tmp
12) +~JF7876557427734797684.tmp
#? 4
+~JF3334986634800781310.tmp
Do you want to delete files ?
y
UserInput is ::  y
Reply is ::  4
No

Comment: Please add your output in your question, not in comment :)

Comment: now delete  the comment ;-) Good luck.

Comment: where do you think REPLY is being set? And why would you want a variable to hold a value that would be like "Y" ? Learn to use the shell debugger feature `set -vx` to see what block/lines of code will be executed and lines with `+` at the front show the values substituted. (`set +vx` to turn off debugging). Your problem will be obvious. Good luck.

Comment: I guess REPLY being set implicitly by shell interpreter(Read some where in documentation). Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PS3="Pick a file number to delete (or Ctrl-C to quit): "
select f in *.tmp ; do echo rm "$f" ; done
```

Then remove the `echo` to make it actually delete files.

Comment: Note: `select` can't tag groups of files easily.  Methods [using `vipe` or `iselect`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313692/165517) are less work.

Comment: Correct so what is the way to deal with it manually ?  Like vipe or is elect seems to be 3rd party libraries which are not allowed.

Comment: D'oh, s/`vipe`/`vidir`/.

Comment: @KiranTeki, The Q. doesn't mention tagging, just menu based file deletion, and `select` can do that much.